# Total minutes streamed within 60 days from launch?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle12c

I need to find the total minutes streamed per title within first 60 days from launch date:

#### xx table:

title_id **integer**
minutes_streamed **float**
streamstartdate **date (yyyymmdd hh:ss)**

#### yy table:

genre **varchar**
launch_date **date (yyyymmdd hh:ss)**

```
SELECT xx.title_id, yy.genre, SUM(xx.minutes_streamed) AS total_minutes
  FROM xx
  JOIN yy
    ON xx.titleid = yy.titleid
 WHERE xx.streamstartdate BETWEEN yy.launch_date + 60 
   AND yy.launch_date
 GROUP BY 1, 2
```

Is this the correct approach to take/any other, more 'elegant' ways to do this?

Comment: Never mind the "approach" - even the syntax is wrong. In Oracle you can't `group by 1, 2` and expect 1 and 2 to be expanded to expressions in `select`. You can do that for `order by` (which is processed after the projection step - the `select` step) but you can't do it for `group by`, which is processed before projection, not after it. Logical impossibility.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your method is fine, but this logic is off:

```
WHERE xx.streamstartdate between yy.launch_date+60 and yy.launch_date
```

The limits for between must be  and .  So:

```
WHERE xx.streamstartdate between yy.laucn_date and yy.launch_date+60
```

Comment: Don't have enough street cred to upvote but thanks, the answer helped me!